# Accounts associations

Tags: discussion, meta, linked-accounts

Hello

I have a question about accounts association: When I look under the tab 'account' I can see all the sites where I have an associated account. OK. But I can see 'meta.stackoverflow' but I cannot see the other 'meta' where I have an account. Is the meta of stackoverflow in some way special ?

Am I missing something ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

Check out this post on [Per Site Metas](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/new-per-site-metas/) from the Stack Overflow blog. The relevant quote is:

> **Meta Stack Overflow will serve as the “National Capital” where we process feedback not just for Stack Overflow but for the core engine itself**

(Jeff's emphasis not mine).

Comment: So it deserve a distinct account from its parent, and the others do not ?

Comment: The answer to my question, after reading your link more carefully, is "yes".